# Melting probes in low pressure environment

Tags: probe, moons, europa, ice

The [icy moons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icy_moon) in our solar system [Enceladus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enceladus) und [Europa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europa_(moon)) are very interesting targets for research because they sport deep oceans of liquid water under their thick shells of ice. But above that icy shell there is no atmosphere worth talking about (it IS worth talking about because of it's composition but for our purposes it does not matter because it's so thin).

To get under the ice, a [melting probe](https://sci.esa.int/web/sci-fmp/-/40386-melting-probe) seems like a really cool solution because you basically only need to heat the tip of your probe and gravity will do the rest to help you get trough the ice.

There has been research done on the dynamics of such probes in Low-G environments and how to prevent the probe from getting [stuck because of refreezing water](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.04883).

Another problem is mentioned in this paper but was explicitly left out of the scope of the study: **How do you start "digging"?** (and that's the question I'd like to see answers to)

That the start can be tricky could be seen with the [mole on mars](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/jpl/nasa-insight-s-mole-ends-its-journey-on-mars). Now, we don't know much about the ice on the icy moons (for example if it could contain rock like lumps of salt because the oceans beneath the ice are assumed to have high [salinity levels](https://www.universetoday.com/151050/how-salty-is-enceladus-ocean-under-the-ice/)). But let's assume they pose no problem and we can "just start to dig".

If we apply heat to the ice at the surface it will sublimate immediately. So there will be no film of water to conduct or convect heat. So there is no water layer to stabilize and "lubricate" the probe. And part of the produced vapor will probably freeze again almost immediately on any cold surface surrounding it.

Only when the hole closes behind the probe and it can build up some pressure it will be able to use water from molten ice to get down trough the ice...

Facing all those issues:
**How would you start your digging process on the surface ice of an icy moon with almost not atmosphere at temperatures around 100K?**

Comment: This sounds interesting, could you clarify what you are actually asking?

Comment: I've added the question at the end. It's really hard to try to condense all the questions I have into a single one...

Comment: I envisage other problems. Would the probe be tethered & would it be connected to surface equipment via a communications cable & other service cables (electricity, etc.)? Problem 1: without a cable, if a probe could get through the ice & into the water below, how would it communicate with Earth & let us know it discovered a fish? Problem 2: with a cable, if the hole freezes over as the probe descends to the water below how does one ensure the cable can also freely travel down the hole with the probe and not be constricted by refrozen ice?

Comment: I hope to come to this later when I have more time, but other thoughts are: (1) having the sides of the probe heated as well as the nose would ensure greater likelihood of getting the probe through the ice. (2) it might be better to reduce the surface area of contact with the ice by having three or five heated fins along the sides of the probe, similar to blades on ice skates.

Comment: @Fred You can spool the cable from the probe rather than from the surface.

Comment: @Fred very interesting. Wanes spooling from the Probe itself is a good solution. I'm not sure how big a spool of 50km of cable would have to be (it's assumed that the ice in Enceladus is between 25km and 50km I think). I guess, we'd only leave a communications dish on the surface because surviving in the harsh radiation on the surface is hard. For heat and energy I imagine an RTG. But would the channel ever close? Or would we blast out more like a crater at the surface?

Comment: For communications, a cable may not be required if [very low frequency radio communications](http://submarinecommunications.weebly.com/low-frequency-radio.html) can be utilized between the submersed probe and a communications station, or a number of such stations on the surface.  I'm unclear why you are suggesting a blasted crater. Would it act as a reflective surface for a radio antenna or as an initial starting position for the probe to start descending into the ice?

Comment: @Fred about the crater: my fear is that if we sublimate ice, the created gas will be accelerated away from the heat source at high speed and maybe take some debris with it, leading to a sand blast effect (especially if the surface is more like snow and not solid ice). So our heated probe would not create a nice narrow hole in which it is stabilized but more like a crater... I have no clue if this could happen.

Comment: Any potential cratering affect could be controlled by the initial rate of ice melting & probe decent. Until the probe is well encapsulated within the ice have a *very slow* rate of decent which would allow the sublimating ice enough time to vacate the hole. Later, the rate of ice melting & probe decent might be able to be increased. Alternatively, and this would add mass to the whole package which would be undesirable. Create the collar of the hole using a drill. When the hole is deep enough discard the drill & place the probe in the hole. ...

Comment: ... If the drill produced ice cuttings backfill the hole with the ice cuttings to encapsulate & seal the probe in the hole. This would increase the complexity of the process, which offers greater opportunity for something to malfunction, but it could be an option.

Comment: Maybe the drill portion could be around the melting probe and stay close to the surface and act as a seal for the hole after releasing the melting probe? But as you said: complexity and mass!